# In asp.net core, are empty string converted to NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, data-annotations

Assuming I have a `form`, and the value of `""` is selected when the `form` is sent from the view to the `controller` to the `action method`, will `asp.net core` convert the empty string to a `NULL` value?

If I do not make the Boolean property nullable for the `[required]` attribute, it gives me this error: **The value '' is invalid.**

Does this mean that: `""` is evaluated as `NULL`, the Boolean property does not allow `NULL`, asp.net core returns a error saying that you can not pass a empty `string` to the `Model` property because it is not nullable because `asp.net core` converts the empty string to a `NULL`?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but note that `string.Format("Look at this: '{0}'", (string)null)` will result in `Look at this: ''` so perhaps it's just how the message is being populated with data for display.

Comment: What boolean property are you talking about?

Comment: public class Model{   [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please specify a option")]
        public bool? Options { get; set; }   }

Comment: A nullable boolean can represent true, false and at least „I have no idea!“ (null) and an empty string is not true and not false - so the best match is „I have no idea!“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that **the Options field here is the type of** **`bool(not string)`**.

**`The only content it can receive is true or false or null`**, whether you enter an empty string or a string other than true or false, it will recognized as null.

The attribute of `Reuqired` indicates that the Options field **cannot be null**,because **`Options is a bool type`**, so after you enter an empty string, the empty string is converted to a null value, and due to the restriction of the reuqired attribute, it cannot be null, so it will remind you invalid.

If you want to allow Options to receive null values, you only need to remove the reuqired attribute.

In the premise of the Required attribute limitation, I did a code test, you can refer to:

[image]

Comment: You did correct the questioner his misunderstanding, but it didn't answer the question :)

Answer (score 20):

MVC model binding does support binding an empty string as either a null or empty string, depending on metadata.

You can control that behaviour per field with attributes;

```cs
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
public string Property { get; set; }
```

Or override that behaviour globally by implementing a custom `IDisplayMetadataProvider`.

```cs
public class DisplayProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Key.ModelType == typeof(string))
            context.DisplayMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
    }
}
// in .AddMvc(o => ...) / AddControllers(o => ...) / or an IConfigure<MvcOptions> service
[MvcOptions].ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new DisplayProvider());
```

Or convert values in any way you like by providing your own `IModelBinder` / `IModelBinderProvider`.

```cs
public class StringBindProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private StringBinder stringBinder = new StringBinder();
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
            return stringBinder;
        return null;
    }
}
public class StringBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);
            var str = value.FirstValue?.Trim();
            if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
                str = null;
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(str);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
// see above
[MvcOptions].ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new StringBindProvider());
```

Comment: Please, how exactly do I "override that behaviour globally by implementing a custom IDisplayMetadataProvider or by providing your own IModelBinder / IModelBinderProvider"? I spent hours googling found nothing :(

Comment: Answer updated to include examples. Probably the best source of inspiration is reading https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore to see how everything actually works.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know, that's where I spend most of my time :). Still can't figure out how to use a custom string-binder with one parent type only (without marking 119 properties with `DisplayFormat`) But this is very helpful, I'll dig further from here.

Comment: Whoever thought this was a good idea to have empty become null bye default needs to be spanked

Answer (score 0):

No they are not - the message says "The value '' is invalid." which is how an empty string looks like.

Comment: If that is the case, why does the error go away when I make the property in the Model class nullable? For example if I have a Boolean property in my class `[Required(ErrorMessage ="Please specify a option")] public bool Options { get; set; }` it produces a error, but when I change the Boolean to nullable the error goes away, `public bool? Options { get; set; }.`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set value for **boolean** if you don't want to set required field. You need to send `false` if it is empty.