# Pass empty string in Postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to build a web API by VS.net and test it use Postman, I would like to pass an empty string through Postman, but it is a null value instead of empty string at .net side, any idea? thanks.

**Postman**
[image]

**.Net Web API**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false, NullDisplayText = "empty")]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull?view=net-5.0

can you try adding this :

You can also set it globally

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60749297/6793637

Comment: @user postman can it's the .net that converts empty string to null it seems