# Is there a way to send empty strings in a query parameter array in swagger for .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am working on a NET6.0 controller endpoint where I want the user to be able to provide two query parameters that will be arrays of strings. One of the arrays should require all items in the array to have a value (a guid), while the other should be able to accept null or empty values.

Below is the code I have currently:

Program.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
}
```

NewController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("company/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class NewController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{entityId:int}/lookup")]
    public IActionResult LookUpBeforeCreate(
        [FromRoute] int entityId,
        [BindRequired, FromQuery(Name = "attr")] IEnumerable<Guid> attributes,
        [BindRequired, FromQuery(Name = "val")] IEnumerable<string?> values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("attributeGuids:");
        foreach (var guid in attributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {guid}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("attributeValues:");
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Value is null");
            }
            else if (value.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Value is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Value: {value}");
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Current swagger page:

[image: Current swagger page]

Currently, I am unable to send an empty string, and can only send null values by leaving the swagger fields empty. Is there any way I can configure the endpoint/swagger to allow me to send null and empty values?

Comment: you can set an attribute in model or binded property that controls the behavior (null or empty)... it's "ConvertEmptyStringToNull".  You just set that to false for "".  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735864/in-asp-net-core-are-empty-string-converted-to-null

Comment: by default empty strings will be nulls (for I think asp.net-core>3.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment reply to my original post answered the question. Thank you browsermator.

The answer can be found here:

[In asp.net core, are empty string converted to NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735864/in-asp-net-core-are-empty-string-converted-to-null)

Answer (score 1):

By leaving the swagger fields empty, the values in httpcontex is empty, but it is converted to null in controller parameter.
So you can use the `values = Request.Query["val"]` directly like

```
public IActionResult LookUpBeforeCreate(
            [FromRoute] int entityId,
            [BindRequired, FromQuery(Name = "attr")] IEnumerable<Guid> attributes,
            [BindRequired, FromQuery(Name = "val")] IEnumerable<string?> values)
        {
            values = Request.Query["val"];
            ...
```

Then the value output is empty when you leave the swagger fields empty.
[image]